# read csv file from given index to index in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rubygems

I have very huge file in millions of rows and I want to insert them into database but I can't create or import simultaneously because it blocks db and takes lots of ram. So, I want to make jobs who reads index to index from csv file( Ex. first job reads 0 to 1000 rows other job reads 1000 to 2000 like wise) but I think CSV.foreach don't have this kind of feature and I can't send 1000 rows data in argument of job and can't open this file in every job. So, please guide me

After getting the path of file I read total lines(suppose 1 million) and divided into 1000 jobs where in each job I give filepath and index from where job has to start reading.
In each job

```
def perform(file_name, index){

    CSV.foreach(file_name, :headers => true) do |row| # want to start with index*1000 
        hash = row.to_hash
        if if i>= index*1000 + 1000
             Table.import arr_hash
             arr_hash = []
             break if i>= index*1000 + 1000
        end
        arr_hash<<Table.new(hash)
    end
    if arr_hash
      Table.import arr_hash
    end
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow community. 
Could you please show some code or what you have researched regarding to your question so far ?

Comment: please see the changes in question

Comment: you can take a look at using the File class with Enumerator::Lazy https://blog.honeybadger.io/using-lazy-enumerators-to-work-with-large-files-in-ruby/. And process the lines with CSV::Row afterwards. Just an idea ☺️

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get in done by using [Smarter CSV](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)

```
SmarterCSV.process('csv_file_path', {:col_sep => ",", :force_utf8 => true, :chunk_size => 1000}) do |chunk|
  # process your chunk here
  # assign each chunk to a Job to process 1000 rows per job
end
```

Comment: I think this don't work because I want to validate data before inserting row and I'm generating jobs to process   chunk of rows so index to index is recommended. Thanks for help

Comment: @Tell_404_not_today you mention "Ex. first job reads 0 to 1000 rows other job reads 1000 to 2000 like wise" in the code above the first chunk would be for first job to run 0 to 2000 rows, and the next chunk would be for the next job to run 2000 to 4000 rows. And this is exactly what you want right? Sorry I had chunk_size as 2000 but you can change it 1000

Comment: @ tkhuynh as per I understand your answer actually I can't give chunk of 1000 rows in argument in job because it's to big for argument. So, I have to gave file path and read rows according to index to index.